# How to execute a multiple line configure command using Mac OS X terminal?

Tags: macos, mac

I am reading a nice article about [upgrading php on mac os x mountain lion](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/).

At the Install part of the document the author says that the user must execute a multiple line configure command.
What is the easiest way to do it, using mac os terminal?
Thank you.

PS : I have executed yesterday the configure command without the parameters.
Can this action cause any problems with the re-execution of configure command (with parameters this time)?

Comment: Re-execution of configure wont cause any major changes unless you perform `make && sudo make install`.

You may collect commands/multiple-line commands required & save it to [Shell Script](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/) and execute it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Mac OS X the default shell (Terminal.app calls) is Bash. In this case, you can use the `\` character to continue a line if needed. This is shown in the tutorial you link to. Other assistance may be gained from reading about Mac OSX [Shell Scripting Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-CH237-SW3).

```
./configure  \
--prefix=/usr  \
--mandir=/usr/share/man  \
--infodir=/usr/share/info  \
--sysconfdir=/private/etc  \
```

etc

Typically you only need to run the configure command once with your options, then `make` for subsequent builds. You *could* put the commands into a script to run, of which you can then just run that one file to execute your commands:

makeProg.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /prog/dir

./configure  \
 --prefix=/usr  \
 --mandir=/usr/share/man  \
 --infodir=/usr/share/info  \
 --sysconfdir=/private/etc  \

make
```

Comment: The default shell is bash, not tcsh.

Comment: @slhck Thanks! I don't have a Mac, so I' can't verify the shell. However, according to what I read from [Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005) it states the `The default shell (or command-line interface) used in Mac OS X 10.0 through 10.2.8 is tcsh ...`, therefore my assumption.

Comment: Well, through 10.2.8 – which was released in 2002. The very same support article mentions bash, which is still correct until now.